# "already exists" error when using ManyToMany relationship between the same two models

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

```
class Product( models.Model ):  
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name="Name", max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    the_products_inside_combo = models.ManyToManyField('self', verbose_name="Products Inside Combo", help_text="Only for Combo Products", blank=True)
```

However, I got this error when I tried to put the duplicate values:

> From_product-to_product relationship with this From product and To
>   product already exists.

[Screencap of the error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjxiv.jpg)

Comment: Are you using any forms ? Is that your full model ?

Comment: the model have more fields, but i removed it because the problematic one is the "the_products_inside_combo "

Comment: basically i cannot enter the same product twice. That's the only problem. I Could use a textfield (ID) but that would be tough for the data-entry because they need to enter the ID manually instead of just selecting products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each pair `(Product, Product)` must be unique. This is why you get `already exists` error.

> Behind the scenes, Django creates an intermediary join table to
>   represent the many-to-many relationship.

What do you want to do is to have many-to-many relationship between two models (nevermind that they are the same) with additional information stored - quantity (so you would have `ProductA = 2x ProductB + ...`.

In order to model this relationship you will have to create intermediary model and use `through` option. Documentation explains it very well, so have a look:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany

**Update**

Here is minimal working example:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name='Name', max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    products = models.ManyToManyField('self', through='ProductGroup', symmetrical=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class ProductGroup(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey('Product', related_name='+')
    child = models.ForeignKey('Product', related_name='+')
```

and admin models:

```
class ProductGroupInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Product.products.through
    fk_name = 'parent'

class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        ProductGroupInline,
    ]

admin.site.register(Product, ProductAdmin)
admin.site.register(ProductGroup)
```

As you can see recursive `Product`-`Product` relation is modeled with `ProductGroup` (`through` parameter). Couple of notes:

1. Many-to-many fields with intermediate tables must not be symmetrical, hence `symmetrical=False`. [Details](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.symmetrical).
2. Reverse accessors for `ProductGroup` are disabled (`'+'`) (in general you can just rename them, however, you don't want to work with `ProductGroup` directly). Otherwise we would get `Reverse accessor for 'ProductGroup.child' clashes with reverse accessor for 'ProductGroup.parent'.`.
3. In order to have a nice display of ManyToMany in admin we have to use inline models (`ProductGroupInline`). Read about them in documentation. Please note, however, `fk_name` field. We have to specify this because `ProductGroup` itself is ambiguous - both fields are foreign keys to the same model.
4. Be cautious with recurrency. If you would define, for example, `__str__` on `Product` as: `return self.products` having `ProductGroup` with the same parent as the child you would loop infinitely.

[image: Admin example]

5. As you can see in the screencap pairs can be duplicated now. Alternatively you would just add quantity field to `ProductGroup` and check for duplication when creating objects.

Comment: i am so sorry, but i am quite new with this. Can you give a simple code example with the admin model code?